# Why does NDSolve and NIntegrate not give the same result?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

[image]
I have plotted solution of two equivalent equations one in Integral form (right chart) the other in Differential form (left chart) using NDSolve and NIntegrate but they give me completely different graphs. Can somebody explain why this is happening?

My NIntegrate code for the right hand chart:

```
Subscript[Ω, rad] = 10^-4;
Subscript[Ω, mat] = 0.3;
Subscript[Ω, Λ] = 0.7; 
Subscript[H, 0] = 2*10^-18;
c = 3*10^8;
Subscript[a, 0] = 10^-10;
H[z_] := Subscript[H, 
0]*(Subscript[Ω, rad] (1 + z)^4 + 
 Subscript[Ω, mat] (1 + z)^3 + 
 Subscript[Ω, Λ])^0.5;
Plot[6 (1 + x)^3*
 NIntegrate[(H[z] - (1 + z) H'[z])/(1 + z)^4, {z, x, 100000}], {x, 0,100000}]
```

The NDSolve code for the left hand chart:

```
Subscript[Ω, rad] = 10^-4;
Subscript[Ω, mat] = 0.3;
Subscript[Ω, Λ] = 0.7;
Subscript[H, 0] = 2*10^-18;
c = 3*10^8;
Subscript[a, 0] = 10^-10;
Subscript[z, i] = 10^5;

H[z_] := Subscript[H,0]*(Subscript[Ω, rad] (1 + z)^4 + Subscript[Ω, mat] (1 + z)^3 +Subscript[Ω,Λ])^0.5;
ϵ[z_] := H'[z]/H[z] (1 + z);

s = NDSolve[{(1 + z)^2 ϕ''[z] - (2 - ϵ[z]) (1 + z) ϕ'[z]== 6 (1 - ϵ[z]), ϕ[0] == 0, ϕ'[0] == 0}, ϕ, {z, 0, Subscript[z, i]}];
Z[z_] := -((c*ϕ'[z] H[z] (1 + z))/Subscript[a, 0])^2 

Plot[Evaluate[-((c*ϕ'[z] H[z] (1 + z))/Subscript[a, 0])^2 /.s], {z, 0, 10^5}]
```

The relevant equations are $$Z=-(\frac{c \dot{\phi}}{a_0})^2$$
dot is derivative with respect to time and ' is derivative with respect to $z$ (Note: capital Z and small z are different)$$\frac{dz}{dt}=-H(1+z)$$
and $$\phi(t)=6\int_{t_i}^{t}\frac{dt'}{a^3(t')}\int_{t_i}^{t'}dt''a^3(t'')[\dot{H(t'')}+H^2(t'')]$$

Comment: We can't explain without seeing your specific code, preferably a simplified version that shows the same behavior.

Comment: sure I am gonna copy the code and paste it here

Comment: I ahve written the codes now

Comment: Would you mind also mentioning a bit of background on where you got these equations from? The most obvious recommendation I can give at the moment is for you to use exact constants (e.g. `1/2` instead of `0.5`).

Comment: I have tried it, it doesn't change anything, I will put the relevant equations here

Comment: Not sure about how well `Subscript` is handled. Personally I have come to avoid it as the devil will holy water. As I don't want to worry about `Downvalues` or not I often end up simply using variable names like `\[CapitalOmega]rad` in one symbol.

Comment: I do not feel that you have given all relevant information so that one can understand what you are doing in your code from the equations. But maybe I am mistaken. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found my mistake. It was on the initial condition if we take $$\phi(zi)=0$$ and $$\phi'(zi)=0$$ the both methods will give the exact same solution.